# How to use a different pre-trained BERT model with bert_score

Tags: bert-language-model, transformer-model

I want you to use different pretrain bert model embeddings for the bert score. How can I do that?
P, R, F1 = score(cand, ref, lang="bn", model_type="distilbert-base-uncased",  verbose=True)
In model_type if use my pretain model then it gives a keyError.